# docker 1.7 multiple port mapping at run failure

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, docker

Background:

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Docker 1.7 - Virtual Interface with its own IP specfically for use with Docker.

Running Wordpress Latest with linked MySQL 5.7 each with their own data containers.

I need to map ports 80 & 443 to the Wordpress container to enforce SSL site wide.

This run string works perfectly:

```
docker run --name Web --link db-server:mysql -d -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=WP -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=admin -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=somepassword -p 172.31.25.94:80:80 --volumes-from wp-data wordpress
```

When I run this string I get an error:

```
docker run --name Web --link db-server:mysql -d -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=WP -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=admin -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=somepassword -p 172.31.25.94:80:80 —p 172.31.25.94:443:443 volumes-from wp-data wordpress:latest
```

Error message:

*Unable to find image '—p:latest' locally
Invalid repository name (—p), only [a-z0-9-_.] are allowed*

I have read the Docker documentation and Googled for this issue and from everything I have found this should work. Is there something I am missing or is this not possible in 1.7?

Comment: Your second "-p" argument isn't actually "-p" it's "—p". Just change that to a hyphen and it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, typos strike again.